# How to force sed to print what it does with my file?

Tags: sed

How to force sed to print what it does with my file?

My `text01.txt` file:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
c
ee
```

My code:

```
sed -i 's/c/X/g' ./text01.txt
```

I want to get in terminal something like this:

```
sed: line 3 change ccc to XXX
sed: line 5 change c to X
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -i"bak" 's/c/X/g' text01.txt && diff text01.txt text01.txtbak
```

will give you a diff summary. like:

```
3c3
< XXX
---
> ccc
5c5
< X
---
> c
```

You can read `diff` man page, to adjust the diff output, e.g. with `-c/-u/-y...` options as you like.

If you want to get exactly same format you described, you can do some work on diff output as well.

Comment: `diff -y file <(sed 's/c/X/g' file) | nl | grep '|'`

Answer (score 0):

This comes pretty close to your requirement:

```
$ paste <(cat -n text01.txt) <(sed 's/c/X/g' ./text01.txt)
     1  aaa aaa
     2  bbb bbb
     3  ccc XXX
     4  ddd ddd
     5  c   X
     6  ee  ee
```

`cat -n` prepends line numbers, and the `paste` command with process substitution prints the file and the sed output next to each other.

Or, more elaborate, with awk:

```
awk '{ getline mod_line < ARGV[2]
       if ($0 != mod_line) {
           printf "sed line %d change %s to %s\n", NR, $0, mod_line }
}' text01.txt <(sed 's/c/X/g' text01.txt)
```

This reads, for each line of `text01.txt`, the corresponding line as modified by sed. If they are different, the line number and both lines get printed:

```
sed line 3 change ccc to XXX
sed line 5 change c to X
```

plus an awk warning because it [tries to close an anonymous pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156084/why-does-process-substitution-result-in-a-file-called-dev-fd-63-which-is-a-pipe) – this can be suppressed by redirecting stderr, i.e., appending `2> /dev/null` to the command.

The closest thing to sed "built-in" debugging is the `l` command, which prints the current content of the pattern space. If you'd like to go all in, there are proper debuggers, for example [sedsed](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed/).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e 'h;/c/!b;s//X/g;H;x;s/\n/ to /;s/^/sed: changed /w/dev/stdout' -e 'x' file
```

This makes a copy of each line in the hold space (HS) and if the substitution pattern does not match, no further action takes place. Otherwise, the substitution is made on the line in the pattern space (PS) and this is appended to the HS. Focus is then changed to the HS and format of before and after effected. The formated line is then written out to the standard output i.e. the terminal and finally focus is reverted to the PS so that the substituted line is included in the original updated file.